# Randomizer has issues

Tags: python

I am trying to create a random array that takes in an argument to determine the length with a predefined inner array. Eg: [(0,0,0) , (1,1,1)]. I am getting this error whenever I perform a run on it and it is really confusing me.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-19c4ef96b4f6> in <module>()
      2 
      3 data = [(1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)]
----> 4 w1 = randomizer(4)
      5 print(w1)
      6 

<ipython-input-42-5818ce3b89d1> in randomizer(w)
      4   j = 0
      5   i = 0
----> 6   while ( j <= w -1):
      7     while( i <  3):
      8 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

here is the code with the call:

```
def randomizer(w):
  newarray = []
  w = []
  j = 0
  i = 0
  while ( j <= w -1):
    while( i <  3):

      integer_list = float(decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(1,10))/10)
      newarray.append(integer_list)
      i += 1
    w.append(newarray)
    j += 1

  return w

Data = [ ( (0,0), 0 ), ( (0,1), 1 ), ( (1,0), 1), ( (1,1), 0 ) ]

data = [(1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)]
w1 = randomizer(4)
print(w1)



r = [0,1,1,0]

#neuralNetLearn (l, data, r, w, v)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You set `w = []` and then do `w - 1`. What do you expect `[] - 1` to be? I don't know what that means and neither does python, hence the error. Maybe you should choose a different name so you don't override the argument `w`. (This is a good lesson in picking meaningful variable names).

Comment: oh I feel dumb. Thank you!

Comment: No worries...everyone's been there.